# Can we play .flv files in html5 video tags in ipad?

Tags: ipad, browser, flv, html5-video, jwplayer

We currently have a system working on chrome,ie7 and mozilla. We have jwplayer that plays .flv  videos on these browsers. We have now to support the play of videos in ipad. Will it be possible if we upgrade the jwplayer to version 5 which supports html5 video tags. Will html5 video tags in ipad be able to support play of .flv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jwplayer works fine on the iPad but you will need another video type for ipad support. The iPad will not play FLV file types, as shown on the [iPad Video specs page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/):

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format